# Linked "Combos" not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/kuj2cz5g/

In the code, I call GetYears to fill a `<ul>` with data. When a year is clicked on, it is supposed to append the selected year to the text of the `flyout` then load the makes `<ul>`
But, what is happening is it is "looping" through the years and calling yearClick for each year in the list after the that is clicked. Yes, it fills the makes `<ul>` but then begins looping `yearClick()` again.

Can anyone help out here? I can't see the forest for the trees, I guess...;-)

```
var year;
var make;
var model;
var ic;
GetYears();
$("#year-flyout").css("top", $(".m-assisted-decode").position().top);
$("#make-flyout").css("top", $(".m-assisted-decode").position().top  +  40).hide();
$("#model-flyout").css("top", $(".m-assisted-decode").position().top +  75).hide();
$("#parts-flyout").css("top", $(".m-assisted-decode").position().top + 112).hide();

function GetYears() {
    var data = 
[{"year":"2017"},{"year":"2016"},{"year":"2015"},{"year":"2014"},{"year":"2013"},{"year":"2012"},{"year":"2011"},{"year":"2010"},{"year":"2009"}];

    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $("#years").append("<li class=\"year\">" + item.year + "</li>");
        $(".year").on("click", yearClick);
    });
    $("#fa_year").hide();
    $("#year-flyout").show();
}
function yearClick(event) {
    year = $(this).text();
    $("#year_value").attr("placeholder", $("#year_value").attr("placeholder") + ":" + year);
    $("#year-flyout").hide();
    // Get the Makes and populate the Makes Flyout
    GetMakes();
}
function GetMakes() {
   var data = 
[{"make":"ACURA"},{"make":"AUDI"},{"make":"BMW"},{"make":"BUICK"},{"make":"CADILLAC"},{"make":"CHEVROLET"},{"make":"CHRYSLER"},{"make":"DODGE"},{"make":"FORD"},{"make":"GMC"},{"make":"HONDA"},{"make":"HUMMER"},{"make":"HYUNDAI"},{"make":"INFINITI"},{"make":"JAGUAR"},{"make":"JEEP"},{"make":"KIA"},{"make":"LAND ROVER"},{"make":"LEXUS"},{"make":"LINCOLN"},{"make":"MAZDA"},{"make":"MERCEDES-BENZ"},{"make":"MERCURY"},{"make":"MINI"},{"make":"NISSAN\/DATSUN"},{"make":"PONTIAC"},{"make":"PORSCHE"},{"make":"RAM"},{"make":"SAAB"},{"make":"SATURN"},{"make":"SCION"},{"make":"SMART"},{"make":"SUBARU"},{"make":"SUZUKI"},{"make":"TOYOTA"},{"make":"VOLKSWAGEN"},{"make":"VOLVO"}];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $("#makes").append("<li class=\"make\">" + item.make + "</li>");
        $(".make").on("click", makeClick);
    });
    $("#make-flyout").show();
}
function makeClick(event) {
    make = $(this).text();
    $("#make_value").attr("placeholder", $("#make_value").attr("placeholder") + ":" + make);
    $("#make-flyout").hide();
    // Get the Models and populate the Models Flyout
    // GetModels();
}
```

Comment: Move `$(".year").on("click", yearClick);` out of the loop

Comment: OK, let me try it.

Comment: You're using the class to add the eventListener, so attaching it once will work for all of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to attach the event listener after each added `<li>` since you're using the class. Just move it out of the each loop

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $("#years").append("<li class=\"year\">" + item.year + "</li>");
});
$(".year").on("click", yearClick);
```

If you inspect your year element in Chrome inspector, you can see all the attached events on click, and see that it was firing the same event several times.

[image]